# How to spread function into div element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that will handle show/hide and position of tooltip:

```
  tooltip = (e) => {
        // show/hide and position of tooltip
        // get element data
      }
```

And a div elements where i want to spread it:

```
<div {...tooltip} data='This is a tooltip 1'>Some div</div>
<div {...tooltip} data='This is a tooltip 2>Some div</div>
```

So it will look like:

```
<div onmouseover=tooltip(e) onmouseleave=tooltip(e) data='This is a tooltip 1'>Some div</div>
```

How to do it?

Comment: The recommended way to do this is to use `document.getElementById('...').addEventListener(tooltip)`

Comment: otherwise, please fill in more details on this question as to where and how you are trying to "populate" it

Comment: i dont want any unnessary id in element

Comment: give me a sec, i will try to make question more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such predetermined solution for that because this is not a common task to attach same handler to several events. It should be:

```
<div onMouseOver={tooltip} onMouseLeave={tooltip}>Some div</div>
```

If there's a constant need to do this, consider creating a helper:

```
const mouseEnterLeave = fn => ({ onMouseOver: fn, onMouseLeave: fn });
```

Then spread attributes can be applied:

```
<div {...mouseEnterLeave(tooltip)}>Some div</div>
```